# Turn off JavaScript when screen is a set size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, responsive-design

How do I turn Javascript off when my page is viewed on mobiles?

I need a sort of media query that will disable all javascript on a page when viewed on a specific device.

So far I have this but do not know how to actually disable all javascript

```
if(screen.width < 480) { 
    // do any 480 width stuff here, or simply do nothing
    return;
} else {
    // do all your cool stuff here for larger screens
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: I have researched and can't find a result, meaning I came here as a last resort. For advice on how to tackle this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable javascript on mobile websites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005658/disable-javascript-on-mobile-websites)

Answer (score 1):

You could use matchMedia.js (found at [https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/)) and check if the screen is below a certain size.

Eg.
    `if (matchMedia('(max-width: 480px)')) {
        // Run Code Here
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the

```
navigator.userAgent
```

property with Javascript. This will show the used browser and you can determine if its mobile or not.

Documentation:
[userAgent Docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp)

You can do it also width the viewport width of your users browser in pure Javascript:

```
var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
```